# Adding user controls to the WinForms StatusStrip control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Is there any way to add my own user controls to the WinForms StatusStrip control?

I want to create a bindable label so that I can bind the sort order description to my controller.

The status strip seems to allow a StatusLabel control to be added, but this does not implement IBindableComponent which would be needed if the control can be bound to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class BindableToolStripStatusLabel : ToolStripStatusLabel, IBindableComponent

public class BindableStatusBarLabel :  ToolStripLabel, IBindableComponent
{
    private ControlBindingsCollection _bindings;

    private BindingContext _context;

    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new BindingContext();
            }
            return _context;
        }
        set
        {
            _context = value;
        }
    }

    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bindings == null)
            {
                _bindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
            }
            return _bindings;
        }
    }
}
```